# I cant link my css to html

Tags: html, css, django

I tried many things by looking at this site, but I could not find one thing.
When i try to use this code in my django project, django cant found css.
I am new in this and I am very trying to do this right.
I apologize for my bad English.
Please help me.

```css
body{
 background-image:url(honey.jpg);
}
ul{
 margin:0px; padding:0px;
}
ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 display: block;
}
ul li{
 float:left;
 width: 150px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: black;
 font-size:15px;
 line-height:40px;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: .7;
 border:1px solid #285189;
}
ul li a:hover{
 background-color: orange;
}
ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Pcelinje drustvo</a>
    <ul>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Tipovi kosnica</a><ul>
    <li><a href="#">Db</a></li>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lr</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Tehnike pcelarenja</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I tried many things" - good! Show us what you tried! Further, rephrase your "question" to actually contain a question. And try to reduce your code to a [mcve]

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hda2ti this is how it look when i start in django

Comment: Chances are your css file is not where your html file is looking. Your CSS is definitely working working: https://jsfiddle.net/zLreLxba/

Comment: Spelling mistake style.css not stye.css

Answer (score 4):

You have to include `{% load staticfiles %}` above the html tag and  replace the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`
with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">`

Comment: Spelling mistake style.css not stye.css

Answer (score 1):

**See This,**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

*Check where your CSS file is. Check the name of the file. Is the CSS file in the CSS folder? Is the HTML located at the same place as the CSS folder?*

**Remember,**

- Is the CSS in the same directory as the file referencing it?
- Is the CSS in a directory **below**?
- Is the CSS in a directory **above**?

**Relative Paths**

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
  moving forward

**That being said,**

Modify link element,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "style.css" %}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Or Adding RequestContext to the response should load the STATIC_URL variable into the template.

Try changing:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

to:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder with your HTML file, must be a folder name:css, inside this folder put your .css file.

Comment: It is i know how this need to be to work but still don't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to include style.css inside the **static** folder, add **STATIC_ROOT** and **STATIC_PATH** in settings.py file and should follow what @subish has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

please try below HTML code. Refresh : press ctrl+f5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pcelinje drustvo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tipovi kosnica</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Db</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lr</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Tehnike pcelarenja</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: send your current output screen shot.

Comment: I think browser cache. press ctrl+f5.

Comment: please try this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/style.css">